# How to consolidate JS for CAML queries with multiple filters?

Tags: javascript, caml-query, spservices, caml, query

I'm very new at the entire JS/SPServices concept (and JS as a whole) and I'm trying to slim down the amount of JS needed for a few HTML pages.

I have several unordered lists on the HTML page that I am using JS to append list items to. I'm using SPServices "GetListItems" to pull items from a SP list, using CAML queries to filter the items based the value of 4 fields, which I then append the "Title" field of to the unordered lists on the page.

The problem is that I have 24 unordered lists on the page, each of which requires a unique CAML query to filter the same SP list data to get the values for. I'm looking for a more efficient way of writing the JS so that I do NOT have to call the same list 24 times for each page. Here's the beginning of what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "newslist",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy><Where><And><And><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Topic' /><Value Type='Text'>company</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Period' /><Value Type='Text'>Q4 2014</Value></Eq></And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Division' /><Value Type='Text'>legal</Value></Eq></And><Eq><FieldRef Name='area' /><Value Type='Text'>highlights</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") +  "</li>";
        $("#highlights1").append(liHtml);
      });
    }
    });

    $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "newslist",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy><Where><And><And><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Topic' /><Value Type='Text'>company</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Period' /><Value Type='Text'>Q4 2014</Value></Eq></And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Division' /><Value Type='Text'>legal</Value></Eq></And><Eq><FieldRef Name='area' /><Value Type='Text'>downfalls</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") +  "</li>";
        $("#downfalls1").append(liHtml);
      });
    }
    });

    $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "newslist",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy><Where><And><And><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Topic' /><Value Type='Text'>company</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Period' /><Value Type='Text'>Q4 2014</Value></Eq></And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Division' /><Value Type='Text'>legal</Value></Eq></And><Eq><FieldRef Name='area' /><Value Type='Text'>coming soon</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") +  "</li>";
        $("#comingsoon1").append(liHtml);
      });
    }
    });

});
```

For each of the 3 unordered lists to be populated above, the "area" field of the query changes. I then have to repeat these 3 functions another 8 times, only changing the "topic" field once for each of the 8 (and obviously the unordered list selectors).

Any ideas on how to consolidate this?

Comment: Do you need to use SPServices? Why not use REST to query all items from the list, and then use jQuery's `$.grep()` method to query the returned object? You'll only call the list once this way.

Comment: @wjervis Please forgive my inexperience with the subject. if SPServices isn't neccessary for this sole function, then I guess I don't need it. What would a REST query using `$.grep()` look like?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? 2010? 2013? If 2013, are you on prem or SPO?

Comment: @wjervis SP 2010

Comment: ah, not sure what you have available to you in 2010 as far as client object model goes.  I'll see what I can find.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that SPServices is a wrapper for the REST services, so using SPServices *is* using REST.  If you are unfamiliar with SharePoint and JSOM, but you do have a bit of a grasp of how to use SPServices, why ditch that and have to learn something new?  (Especially when that something new is something many people find difficult to work with, which is why SPServices was created in the first place.)

Comment: Also, although querying the list once to retrieve all items and using `$.grep()` to filter will reduce calls to the list, it won't necessarily reduce the amount of JS on your page, because you'll still have to write all the `grep` filter logic to extract the items you want.  My solution below is pretty well "consolidated", into one single block of code for the SPServices call, and then 24 single lines of code to query on each of your filter permutations.  Under the circumstances that seems highly manageable.  Also, I wouldn't worry about 24 calls to the list given your specific CAML queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you refactor the SPServices call into another function, that takes the "area" value, "topic" value, and the list selector as parameters?  You'd still be querying the list 24 times, but it will look a lot cleaner.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    QueryNewsList("highlights", "company", "#highlights1");
    QueryNewsList("downfalls", "company", "#downfalls1");
    QueryNewsList("coming soon", "company", "#comingsoon1");

    // add your other permutations here

});

function QueryNewsList(area, topic, listSelector) {

    var camlQuery = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy><Where><And><And><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Topic' /><Value Type='Text'>" + topic + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Period' /><Value Type='Text'>Q4 2014</Value></Eq></And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Division' /><Value Type='Text'>legal</Value></Eq></And><Eq><FieldRef Name='area' /><Value Type='Text'>" + area + "</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query>";

    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "newslist",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery: camlQuery,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
                $(listSelector).append(liHtml);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This looks good. I'll give it a shot and see how fast the page will load. Thanks!

Comment: Doing it this way, you might even be able to make them `async: true`, that might speed things up a little bit.

Comment: 'async:true' sped it up drastically. Thanks a ton for this!